# Extending the classpath for executable wars/jars

Tags: spring-boot

I have a number of bootified executable wars that support standalone execution as well as deployment to a container (same artifact - cool - love spring-boot!).

Now I need to allow the customer to override the embedded jdbc drivers in the standalone execution scenario by putting the jar in some standard location(s) I define (and bake into the build - I.E. no -D args should be required by the customer *[this implies the additional external classpath locations need to be earlier in the classpath]*.

I've looked at ZIP layout and [PropertiesLauncher](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/loader/PropertiesLauncher.html) but its not clear to me this can be achieved out of the box.

Can the [PropertiesLauncher](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/loader/PropertiesLauncher.html) be configured such that it behaves that same as the war/jar launcher but with an augmented classpath when executed standalone?

Any hints welcome.